# R - adf.test() lags

Tags: r

I've to do unit root test in R.
I want to know which method use `tseries::adf.test()` in order to compute the lag length.

With other functions such as `CADFtest()` and `ur.df()`  we can select the criterion to compute the lag length.

Comment: Maybe this is better for https://stats.stackexchange.com/. adf will perform a unit root test for the first lag AR(1). Check the parameter `k`

Comment: I've see the `k` but I don't understand the meaning

Comment: Where is this question?